# Definition list with inline pairs

Tags: css, list, line, inline, definition

I'm trying to create a definition list of term-definition pairs, each pair existing on a single, separate line. I've tried making `dt`s and `dd`s `display:inline`, but then I lose the line breaks between the pairs. How do I make sure I have a line for each pair (and not for each individual term/definition)?

Example:

```
<dl>
<dt>Term 1</dt><dd>Def 1</dd>
<dt>Term 2</dt><dd>Def 2</dd>
</dl>
```

yielding:

```
Term 1 Def 1
Term 2 Def 2
```

The CSS for making them inline would be:

```
dt,dd{display:inline;}
```

yielding:

```
Term 1 Def 1 Term 2 Def 2
```

...which is not what I want (line breaks between pairs missing).

Comment: Please provide a complete, working code example, as per the question requirements in the FAQ.

Comment: Does it need to be more complete than the one I added in the edit?

Comment: Please include the related CSS.

Comment: You just want more space between pairs?

Comment: (I didn't vote to close)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this:

```
dt, dd { float: left }
dt { clear:both }
```

Add margin-bottom to `dt dd` if you'd like more space between them..

Comment: This broke other things for me like *p* that followed *dl* ran over *dl*.

Comment: @mlt To avoid that you also need `dl { overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: Adding `dl { overflow: hidden; }` did not help

Answer (score 39):

Another solution:

```
dt:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
dt, dd {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: This works in new browsers, but not in stock android 4.3 or before

Comment: This is much better than `float` based solutions, because it maintains the vertical height of the `<dl>` element.

Comment: This solution is just what I wanted as it works well with `text-align: center` too. My only minor issue is that copying and pasting the text from the HTML results in one long line, because pseudo-elements are not selected.

Comment: I used `dd:after {...}` Works a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I tried these answers, finally I end up with [this](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/format-dl/).

Which I simplified to:

```
  dl {    
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  dt {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;    
  }
  dt:after {
    content: ":";
  }
  dd {
    margin: 0 0 0 110px;        
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use inline-block and percentage widths. As long as the combined width of dd + dt is greater than 50%.

```
dt, dd {
  display: inline-block;
}

dt {
  width: 50%;
}

dd {
  min-width: 5%;
}
```

I found this gave me a more consistent positioning of the dd elements.

Comment: Actually, the combined width of `dt` + `dd` + `dt` needs to be more than 100% for this to work. I initially tried with a `dt` `width` of 25% and a `dd` `min-width` of 26%, but it didn't have the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution

```
dt {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/vumeyowana/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Best answer, IMHO. I would prefer `right-padding: 1em;` over 'min-width`

Comment: this works only for descriptions that fit in one line.

Answer (score 2):

Andrey Fedoseev's answer does not work in old android (stock browser 4.3).

This does work for that browser and all others I have checked:

```css
dt::before {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  display: block;
  height: .5em;
}

dt, dd {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>AM</dt>
  <dd>Description for am that should span more than one line at narrow screen widths.</dd>
  <dt>PM</dt>
  <dd>this means afternoon.</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "zebra" background or border separating each DT-DD pair, then this will work nicely:

```
dt, dd {
    padding: 8px 6px;
    display: block;
}
dt {
    font-weight: 600;
    float: left;
    min-width: 50%;
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
}
dd:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: #eee;
}
```

This will appear to wrap both items in a row with a grey background. As long as the DT has less vertical height than the DD - which is usually the case.

(Haven't browser tested yet.)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be able to create a list with inline pairs, centrally aligned. Using `dt:before { display; block}` worked well for this, but when copying text from a browser, pseudo elements are ignored so would end up being pasted like this:

```
Term 1: Def 1Term 2: Def 2
```

This is a minor issue, but there's another approach [documented at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl#Wrapping_name-value_groups_in_div_elements):

> **WHATWG HTML allows wrapping each name-value group in a `<dl>` element in a `<div>` element.** This can be useful when using microdata, or when global attributes apply to a whole group, or for styling purposes.

The following solution works well for this:

```
dt, dd {
  display: inline;
}

<dl>
  <div><dt>Term 1:</dt> <dd>Def 1</dd></div>
  <div><dt>Term 2:</dt> <dd>Def 2</dd></div>
</dl>
```