# Looking to display 2 div tags on same line

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div tags that on frontend displays on separate lines. I would like to display them on the same line. Please note the first is the heading and the second is the answer. Here is an example:

```
    <div class="field-label">Type of Institution</div>
    <div class="field-value">Fine Arts Magnet School</div>
```

Current Frontend display:

**Type of Institution**

Fine Arts Magnet School

This is what I want:
**Type of Institution:**
Fine Arts Magnet School

Both heading and text on same line. If text is long, I would like it to wrap under heading.

Comment: I cannot change the div and use better code. This is a plugin and I have limited knowledge with this.

Answer (score 0):

A `<div>` is not the right thing to use. Really it should be

`<dl>
<dt>Type of Institution</dt>
<dd>Fine Arts Magnet School</dd>
</dl>`

Type of Institution

Fine Arts Magnet School

And then as explained here [Definition list with inline pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692424/definition-list-with-inline-pairs)

`dt, dd { float: left }
dt { clear:both }`

or one of the other solutions offered (there are quite a few duplicate questions on this one).

Comment: I cannot change the div and use better code. This is a plugin and I have limited knowledge with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline` or `float: left` (and `clear` after them).

It´s a view of CSS. The second thing is semantic, for pair label-value you should use definition list, so:

```
<style>
dl {overflow: hidden}
dt, dd {float: left;}
dt {width: 150px; clear: left; font-weight: bold;}
</style>

<dl>
    <dt>Type of Institution</dt>
    <dd>Fine Arts Magnet School</dd>

    <dt>Students</dt>
    <dd>3000</dd>
</dl>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jh0j3yg1/

Comment: I cannot change the div and use better code. This is a plugin and I have limited knowledge with this.

Comment: Okay, in this case just use `div {float: left;}`, ideally with any ID/Class to avoid setting float to all divs in page. EDIT: `.field-label, .field-value {float: left;} .field-label {clear: left}`